# Sum and product of Martingale processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Given two Martingale processes $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$, are their sum $(X_t+Y_t)$ and their product $(X_t \times Y_t)$ also Martingale?

If not, will the two $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ being independent grant their sum and product Martingale? Thanks!

Comment: Are you considering $t\in\mathbb N$ or $t\in\mathbb R_+$?

Comment: @Morning: can be both. Will they make difference?

Comment: @steveO: I guess you should make it precise what it means by $X_t+Y_t$ to be a martingale. With respect to the same filtration?  In the discrete case, the martingale structure is relatively simple and you can prove/disprove easily.

Comment: @Morning: When $t \in \mathbb{N}$, for $X_t+Y_t$ to be a martingale, I mean being martingale wrt itself, i.e. $E(X_{t+1}+Y_{t+1}|X_i+Y_i,i=1,...,t)=X_t+Y_t, \forall t \in \mathbb{N}$. Simiarly when $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think it best to look at the martingale property *with respect to a given filtration*. This is the most common in my experience, and fits in naturally with the view of the filtration as representing the observable information up to each time. If you just look at the martingale property with respect to the filtration generated by the individual processes then you are, in some sense, missing some observable events and you cant expext it to behave so well. Maybe there is a good reason in your case, but I'm just pointing out what I consider the best approach is in general.

Comment: Also, the discrete vs continuous time dichotomy makes no difference here.

Comment: @George: Your comment seems like an excellent motivation to look at what happens for different filtrations... And this is exactly what Vershik, Tsirelson, Émery and others are studying. Keywords here are immersion, cosiness, standardness, *hiding a drift*, innovations... See Tsirelson's survey at the ICM'98 http://www.emis.de/journals/DMJDMV/xvol-icm/12/Tsirelson.MAN.html or Émery and Schachermayer's paper http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~schachermayer/pubs/pubabs.php?id=97 for example.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The product of two independent martingales is a martingale--or rather it is or it is not, depending on the precise formulation of the hypothesis! When it is, one says that the martingales are *orthogonal*. This is explained, for example, by [Alexander Cherny](http://alexanderchernyy.com/) in the chapter [Some Particular Problems of Martingale Theory](http://alexanderchernyy.com/pmt.pdf) of the [Shiryaev Festschrift](http://books.google.com/books?id=r7hcwexRIkcC&printsec=frontcover&source=bl&ots=8v4BBzh2rF&sig=mSqgPU-ZXhaD6LmSYMhNn8LuIUo&hl=fr&ei=OIeyTZ_WMsPX8gPAxZjRAQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage).

And yes, the sum of two independent martingales is a martingale but, here again, it might be wise to state the result with some care and, first of all, as mentioned by steveO in a comment, to specify the filtration(s) one is considering.

The trivial version is that if $X$ and $Y$ are two martingales (independent or not) with respect to a given filtration $\mathcal{G}$, then the sum $X+Y$ is also a martingale with respect to $\mathcal{G}$. But what happens if one assumes that $X$ is a martingale with respect to its own filtration $\mathcal{F}^X$ and that $Y$ is a martingale with respect to its own filtration $\mathcal{F}^Y$?

(Recall that the filtration $\mathcal{F}^Z$ of a process $Z$ is defined by $\mathcal{F}^Z_n=\sigma(\{Z_k;k\le n\})$ for every $n$.)

Then, *if $X$ and $Y$ are independent*, $X+Y$ is a martingale with respect to its own filtration $\mathcal{F}^{X+Y}$ but, first, the proof, while not terribly difficult, requires to be careful (and uses more than the linearity of conditional expectations), and, second, for non independent martingales, this becomes horribly wrong.

To get an idea of the problem, consider a given integrable random variable $\xi$ and two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ and try to find conditions guaranteeing that $E(\xi|\mathcal{A}\vee\mathcal{B})=E(\xi|\mathcal{A})$. Is $\xi$ independent of $\mathcal{B}$ enough? No, one has to assume that  $\mathcal{B}$ is independent of $\sigma(X)\vee\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: is this related to the _orthomartingales_? (The reference that I am aware of is _Multiparameter processes_ by Khoshnevisan.) I briefly looked over Cherny's paper. It seems not.

Comment: @Morning: Not in ways that I would be aware of.

Comment: @did Could you please provide an easy example of such two martingales  "...non independent martingales, this becomes horribly wrong". I tried but couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: @grozhd Could you please start with the indication on **exactly this**, which I took pain to add?

Comment: @Did Some of your links appear to be dead.