# product of two continuous martingales under a brownian filtration

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A quick question : I want to know if the product of two **continuous** martingales under a **brownian filtration** could **be a martingale** ? I have particularly the product of an exponential martingale (come from a Girsanov changement of probability) and a general martingale (both under a common probability P).

Obviously, I have read carrefully the Did's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22376/334615) and the reference he gaves (Alexander Cherny : Some Particular Problems of Martingale Theory).

Again, since we are under a brownian filtration is it possible to get the product of two martingales (a priori non-independant) to be a martingale ? or it is not as stronger as stating the independance of the 2 processes ?

Maybe we can make use the martingale representation theorem and find another condition less stronger ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the martingales $X_t:=\int_0^t 1_{\{B_s>0\}}\,dB_s$ and $Y_t:=\int_0^t 1_{\{B_s<0\}}\,dB_s$, where $(B_s)$ is a Brownian motion. The covariation of these two martingales is $\int_0^t1_{\{B_s>0\}}1_{\{B_s<0\}}\,ds=0$, so the product $X_tY_t$ is a martingale.

Comment: Great example, that means that independance is not required everytime. **But** I need (to know if it exists) something general with two martingales under a brownian filtration. One of them is an exponential martingal.

Comment: or maybe it must be studied on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: In general, the product of  two Brownian martingales $X_t=\int_0^t H_s\,dB_s$ and $Y_s=\int_0^t K_s\,dB_s$ will be a (local) martingale if and only if $\int_0^t H_sK_s\,ds=0$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: @the-owner Let $X_t=\exp[\int_0^t1_{\{B_s>0\}}dB_s-\frac12\int_0^t1_{\{B_s>0\}}ds]$ and $Y_t=\exp[\int_0^t1_{\{B_s<0\}}dB_s-\frac12\int_0^t1_{\{B_s<0\}}ds]$, then $X_tY_t=\exp[B_t-\frac{t}2]$ and all $X,Y,XY$ are positive continuous martingales.