# Product of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(Ω,\mathcal F,P)$ be a probability space. Assume that the two sequences $(X_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are independent. For all $n\in\Bbb{N}$, define $Z_n=X_nY_n$ and
$$\mathcal{G}_n=\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\qquad\mathcal{H}_n=\sigma(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\qquad\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$$

If $(X_n,\mathcal{G}_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and $(Y_n,\mathcal{H}_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are martingales, is $(Z_n,\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ still a martingale?

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Do you have an example where the statement holds or fails to hold?

Comment: To write indices in math mode, please use `_{...}`.

Comment: That's too difficult for me, the only intuition that i had, is to say that it's still a martingale by the fact that the two squences are independent and so the result remains in L^1

Comment: Interesting, why did you see fit to delete the mark signaling where the question is in your post?

Comment: sorry, i didn't know that! I thought was a mistake.

Comment: What else does a Martingale need to satisfy? It's not enought to be in $L^{1}$.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22367/sum-and-product-of-martingale-processes