# Why $X_t^θ= B_1(t) \cos θ − B_2(t) \sin θ$ is a martingale?

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t≥0}, \mathcal{P})$ be a filtered probability space. Let $(B_1(t), B_2(t))_{t≥0}$ be a two-dimensional Brownian
motion. Let $ θ\in \mathbb{R}$ and let 
$$ X_t^θ = B_1(t) \cos θ − B_2(t) \sin θ $$

Why $X_t^θ$ is a martingale ?

Comment: If $M_1(t)$ and $M_2(t)$ are two independent martingales with respect to the same filtration, $a_1 M_1(t) + a_2 M_2(t)$ is a martingale with respect to that filtration for any $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22376/16192

Answer (score 0):

For any $t\geqslant 0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X_t^\theta|] &= \mathbb E[|B_1(t)\cos\theta - B_2(t)\sin\theta|]\\
&\leqslant |\cos\theta|\mathbb E[|B_1(t)|] + |\sin\theta|\mathbb E[|B_2(t)|]\\
&\leqslant 2\mathbb E[|B_1(t)|]\\
&= 2\sqrt{\frac{2t}\pi}<\infty,
\end{align}
so that $\{X_t^\theta\}$ is integrable. As for the martingale condition, if $0\leqslant s<t$ then
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[X_t^\theta\mid \mathcal F_s] &= \mathbb E[(X_t^\theta-X_s^\theta+X_s^\theta)\mid\mathcal F_s]\\
&=\mathbb E[X_t^\theta-X_s^\theta\mid\mathcal F_s] + \mathbb E[X_s^\theta\mid\mathcal F_s]\\
&= \mathbb E[X_t^\theta-X_s^\theta] + X_s^\theta\\
&= \mathbb E[B_1(t)\cos\theta-B_2(t)\sin(\theta)] + X_s^\theta\\
&= \cos\theta\mathbb E[B_1(t)] + \sin\theta\mathbb E[B_2(t)] + X_s^\theta\\
&= X_s^\theta,
\end{align}
since $\mathbb E[B_1(t)] = \mathbb E[B_2(t)] = 0$.